# What clock/timer keeps track of Browser Cookie Expiration dates?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

I have a cookie set to expire in 1 minute from now, however, it takes more like 1:50 to elapse before the cookie itself is removed from the browser.

Here is our method to set the cookie:

```
setCookie: function(key, val, ttlInMinutes) {
  var expires = '';
  if (ttlInMinutes > 0) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (ttlInMinutes * 60 * 1000));
    expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
  }
  var domain = '';
  if (SnapABug.getDomain()) {
    domain = '; domain=' + SnapABug.getDomain();
  }
  var other = '';
  if (secureCookies) {
    other = '; Secure';
  }
  document.cookie = key + '=' + val + expires + '; path=/;' + domain + other;
}
```

This outputs the correct future time in the browser:

[image]

I compared my system clock which is set to "automatic".

Let's also assume that the browser doesn't get closed, and the website visitor is active on the site.

My question is:
What keeps track of this expiration time?
Is there a clock/timer inside the browser?

Comment: How are you checking when the cookie expires?

Comment: My guess is that there's no timer at all. When you access `document.cookie` it scans it for expired cookies and removes them.

Comment: Somehow the cookies automatically get removed by the browser.
You can't check for cookie expiration unless that is explicitly set as part of the cookie key:value pair.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you have a browser open without navigation/refresh/open-close tabs, that the expiration date does not get kept track of.  That would require the browser to be running tons of independent threads and to keep track of it is not realistic.
So cookie expiration really only is ideal for when there is navigation/refresh/open-close.